# Python Deployment To CGI Host?

Tags: python, web, cgi, web-scraping, cgi-bin

I have developed a CGI Python application, it works on a local server, but how do I compile it to run it on a remote Python CGI host?

The application uses

```
import cgitb
import cgi
import requests
import cookielib
import bleach
import re
```

Comment: 'compile'? What do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean how do i get this working on remote web server because im importing these libs and im pretty sure that the server doesn't have some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this structure:

```
(root)
 |- html
 |  |- .htaccess
 |  |- ...
 |- lib
    |- lib1
    |  |- script1.py
    |- lib2
       |- script2.py

import sys
for path in ("/lib/lib1", "/lib/lib2",...):
    if not path in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

import script1        # should work with the right paths
```

Aaaand... many providers require certain stuff in '.htaccess' file to make python files executable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question to ask your web hosting company.  I use Dreamhost, and you can view some python cgi [script examples](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Sample_Python_CGI_script) as well as a [wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python) with more information.  This will probably be different for your needs, though.

Comment: So, the extra lib i need will i have to ask them to install it?

Comment: @Arsalan as long as they let you run a python script, you can always append the path to lib to *sys.path*.